# How to extract text value and assign it to variable outside then scope in cypress

Tags: javascript, promise, cypress, pageobjects

I want to somehow get some price values from the page I am on.
I would like to do with cypress the following:

1. get the text from the page element,
2. turn it to a number
3. then save it on the price JS object
4. return the price JS object

This is what I did so far:

```
  getCheckoutPricesBeforeApplyingVoucher() {
    let prices = {
      subtotalPrice: 0,
      totalPrice: 0,
      itemPriceOrderOverview: 0,
      totalPriceOrderOverview: 0,
      totalWithVATOrderOverview: 0
    }
      prices.subtotalPrice = this.getPrice('[data-cy=subtotalPrice]')
      prices.totalPrice = this.getPrice('[data-cy=totalPrice]')
      prices.itemPriceOrderOverview = this.getPrice('[data-cy=itemPriceOrderOverview]');
      prices.totalPriceOrderOverview = this.getPrice('[data-cy=totalPriceOrderOverview]');
      prices.totalWithVATOrderOverview = this.getPrice('[data-cy=totalWithVATOrderReview]');
      cy.log(prices.subtotalPrice);
      cy.log(prices.totalPrice);
      cy.log(prices.itemPriceOrderOverview);
      cy.log(prices.totalPriceOrderOverview);
      cy.log(prices.totalWithVATOrderOverview);
      return prices;
  }

   getPrice(selector) {
    return cy.get(selector)
      .invoke('text')
      .then((text) => {
        return Number(text);
      })
  }
```

But the values that my prices JS object has are all 0 when written in the console with for example `cy.log(prices.subtotalPrice)`. They are not set to the corresponding values from UI elements.
Do you have an advise how to do this properly? Maybe my whole approach should go in different direction?
Thanks!

[EDIT]
I tried this as well, but the result for some reason is still 0 for each value from JS object.

```
  getCheckoutPricesBeforeApplyingVoucher() {
    let prices = {
      subtotalPrice: 0,
      totalPrice: 0,
      itemPriceOrderOverview: 0,
      totalPriceOrderOverview: 0,
      totalWithVATOrderOverview: 0
    }

    cy.get('[data-cy=subtotalPrice]').invoke('text').as('subtotalPrice');
    cy.get('[data-cy=totalPrice]').invoke('text').as('totalPrice');
    cy.get('[data-cy=itemPriceOrderOverview]').invoke('text').as('itemPriceOrderOverview');
    cy.get('[data-cy=totalPriceOrderOverview]').invoke('text').as('totalPriceOrderOverview');
    cy.get('[data-cy=totalWithVATOrderReview]').invoke('text').as('totalWithVATOrderReview');

    prices.subtotalPrice = this.subtotalPrice;
    prices.subtotalPrice = this.totalPrice;
    prices.subtotalPrice = this.itemPriceOrderOverview;
    prices.subtotalPrice = this.totalPriceOrderOverview;
    prices.subtotalPrice = this.totalWithVATOrderReview;

    cy.log(prices.subtotalPrice);
    cy.log(prices.totalPrice);
    cy.log(prices.itemPriceOrderOverview);
    cy.log(prices.totalPriceOrderOverview);
    cy.log(prices.totalWithVATOrderOverview);
    return prices;
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: For Cypress specifically, which uses something that looks like but _isn't_ a promise: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried it with aliases but it still doesn't work for some reason. I have updated my question. Can you help? Any ideas?

Comment: There's a specific example in the docs telling you that won't work, see https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Accessing-Fixtures - _"this.users is not defined because the 'as' command has only been enqueued - it has not run yet"_.

Comment: @jonrsharpe aha, sorry I missed that one. So do you have any suggestions how to approach this? I cannot find my way from the link that Heretic Monkey posted. What would it look like when applying Promises and then principle?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to save those values so I can operate with them later on in the code. I don't need to use them right away in then function. Somehow I would like to save them to this JS object. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress commands like `cy.get(...)` are asynchronous in order to provide retry for asynchronous elements, for example if the data comes from an API.

Mixing Cypress commands with Page Object methods is problematic, because the methods then have to become asynchronous as well.

If you are absolutely sure that the data is present in the page, you can switch to the synchronous `Cypress.$(...)` which will directly set your object properties.

```js
getCheckoutPricesBeforeApplyingVoucher() {
  return {
    subtotalPrice: +Cypress.$('[data-cy=subtotalPrice]').text(),
    totalPrice: +Cypress.$('[data-cy=totalPrice]').text(),
    itemPriceOrderOverview: +Cypress.$('[data-cy=itemPriceOrderOverview]').text(),
    totalPriceOrderOverview: +Cypress.$('[data-cy=totalPriceOrderOverview]').text(),
    totalWithVATOrderOverview: +Cypress.$('[data-cy=totalWithVATOrderReview]').text()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. What approach would you use better? Aliases or synchronous accessor? What would be better practice in your opinion?

Comment: The alias approach looks too noisy and over-complicated. I can't figure out what the test flow is.

Comment: Sorry for being pushy, but I want to understand the pros and cons of both approaches. So the readability is apparently alias con. But what are possible pitfalls I could get into if using this synchronous accessor? Why do I need to be absolutely sure that the data is present in the page? Can you please explain a bit :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure this out using this [article](https://www.stevenhicks.me/blog/2020/02/working-with-variables-in-cypress-tests/)

Here it goes - it has a bit of additional code but I think it is ok as an example:

```
verifyVoucherApplied(voucher) {
    cy.get('[data-cy=textVoucherCode]').should('be.visible').and('have.text', voucher.CHF30.code);
    cy.get('[data-cy=textVoucherValue]').should('be.visible').and('have.text', voucher.CHF30.value);

    this.checkDiscountedPrice('subtotalPrice', voucher.CHF30.value);
    this.checkDiscountedPrice('totalPrice', voucher.CHF30.value);

    cy.get('@itemPriceOrderOverview').then(itemPriceOrderOverviewSaved => {
      cy.get('[data-cy=itemPriceOrderOverview]').invoke('text')
        .then(itemPriceOrderOverview => {
          expect(itemPriceOrderOverview).to.eq(Number(itemPriceOrderOverviewSaved).toFixed(2));
        });
    });

    cy.get('[data-cy=discountOrderOverview]').invoke('text')
      .then(discountOrderOverview => {
        expect(discountOrderOverview.replace(/\s/g, '')).to.eq(voucher.CHF30.value);
      });

    this.checkDiscountedPrice('totalPriceOrderOverview', voucher.CHF30.value);
    this.checkDiscountedPrice('totalWithVATOrderReview', voucher.CHF30.value);
  }

  saveCheckoutPricesBeforeApplyingVoucher() {
    this.saveTextAsNumber('subtotalPrice');
    this.saveTextAsNumber('totalPrice');
    this.saveTextAsNumber('itemPriceOrderOverview');
    this.saveTextAsNumber('totalPriceOrderOverview');
    this.saveTextAsNumber('totalWithVATOrderReview');
  }
  saveTextAsNumber(selector) {
    cy.get(`[data-cy=${selector}]`).invoke('text')
      .then(text => {
        cy.wrap(Number(text)).as(`${selector}`);
      });
  }
  checkDiscountedPrice(selector, discount) {
    cy.get('@' + selector).then(priceBeforeApplyingDiscount => {
      let priceDiscounted = this.applyFixedDiscount(priceBeforeApplyingDiscount, Number(discount));
      cy.get(`[data-cy=${selector}]`).invoke('text')
        .then(price => {
          expect(price).to.eq(priceDiscounted);
        });
    });
  }
  applyFixedDiscount(price, discount) {
    return Number(price + discount).toFixed(2);
  }
```

Comment: ".as(`${selector}`)" can be ".as(selector)", you are not templating anything there.

Comment: Also, you might as well use the synchronous accessor.